# React-Router re renders the wrong component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]

I set the Routes don't function correctly.
Them may go to the component and mention the correct Route, but when I write the URL manually it ends up re-rendering to the home-page or localhost:3001/login.
Do you have any idea why is that happening? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqZmj.png)

Comment: Please add the relevant code and Router config

Comment: In your second  if(tihs.props.isAuth) you have a two same path "/" and different components. But, i dotn think it is problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined the same route to two different components may be that is the issue.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Charges} />
<Route exact path="/" component={Account} />
```

Btw this is not the ideal way to authorize routes.  Try something like this

```
<Route  path="/account" render={() => (isAuth() ? (<Redirect to="/login"/>) : (<Account />))}/>
```

Where is **isAuth()** is a function which returns Boolean value

```
isAuth() => {this.props.isAuth};
```

This will render the Account component if **isAuth()** return true or else it will redirect to login.

and looks like you have `<Redirect to="/login"/>` which should be causing the error.

Comment: Still did not work the way it should be and I have the same problem

Comment: @AshrafUthman I'm not quite getting what you are saying here. I hope you are being redirected to /login when you try to navigate manually. i hope the home page that you are referring here is /login. Please share your code don't post images of your code.